# What causes the bubbles of marshes and swamps?

Tags: science-based, environment

One of the common fantasy scenarios are swamps, marshes, bogs, tar pits or even sewers, with a dark and loomy atmosphere, and gas bubbles popping everywhere. What causes these bubbles? Is it the heat, a specific gas coming from the earth or other phenomenon?

[image: a marsh with gas bubbles]

Comment: This is either a question about the cause of a real world phenomena, or a discussion prompt about a phenomena found in existing works of fiction. In either case as written it isn't about building a fictional world.

Answer (score 3):

**Swamp Gas**, decomposing plant material in the bog or swamp.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsh_gas)

> Methane is the primary gas that makes up the product colloquially
> known as "marsh gas". Much of the biogenic methane produced in nature
> is derived from either acetate cleavage or by the hydrogen reduction
> of carbon dioxide. Methane can also be produced by methanogens,
> archaea that produce methane under anoxic conditions, in a process
> known as methanogenesis. Methanogenic genera Methanosarcina are common
> in marsh environments. They are both known to stimulate methane
> production in aquatic muds and use acetate, methanol, and
> trimethylamine as substrates for methane production.

Also a bonus [google search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS972US973&lei=MRjfYeXEKemYwbkPvNCuKA&q=swamp%20gas%20lights&ved=2ahUKEwilobC35qz1AhVpTDABHTyoCwUQsKwBKAB6BAg_EAE&biw=2133&bih=977&dpr=0.9)

Comment: Important to note: this phenomenon is real.  Real.  REAL, I TELL YOU!

Comment: Microbes farting!?! Pull the other one.